# Python Script stopping for large files

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I wrote this script to classify a shapefile in 5 classes, this works for small files (minor 8000 features), for larger files, the process has stopped. Can make this better?

```
#Load the shape
vrAdubo = QgsVectorLayer(vetor_saida_adubo, "Adubo", "ogr")

if not vrAdubo:
   progress.setText("Erro ao carregar shape resultante Adubo")


#Insert fields area_ha,  classe e kmph
provVrAdub = vrAdubo.dataProvider()
provVrAdub.addAttributes([QgsField("area_ha", QVariant.Double), QgsField("classe", QVariant.Int), QgsField("kmph", QVariant.Double), QgsField("area_class", QVariant.Double),
QgsField("perc_class", QVariant.Double)])
vrAdubo.updateFields()

#Set fields valures
vrAdubo.startEditing()
iterVrAdub = vrAdubo.getFeatures()

#variaveis areas totais por classe
area_cls1 = 0.000
area_cls2 = 0.000
area_cls3 = 0.000
area_cls4 = 0.000
area_cls5 = 0.000

#Setting filds
for featAdubo in iterVrAdub:
    geom = featAdubo.geometry()
    featAdubo['area_ha'] = geom.area() / 10000
    areatt_ad += featAdubo['area_ha'] #area total mapeada
    ct_pol_adu += 1 #contagem de poligonos
    featAdubo['kmph'] = featAdubo['Speed'] * 3.6  

#Classify by ranges
    if featAdubo['AppldRate'] > 0.0000:
        if featAdubo['AppldRate'] < 400.000:
            featAdubo['classe'] = 1
            area_cls1 += featAdubo['area_ha']
        elif featAdubo['AppldRate'] >= 400.000 and featAdubo['AppldRate']< 450.000:
            featAdubo['classe'] = 2
            area_cls2 += featAdubo['area_ha']
        elif featAdubo['AppldRate'] >= 450.000  and featAdubo['AppldRate']< 550.000:
            featAdubo['classe'] = 3
            area_cls3 += featAdubo['area_ha']
        elif featAdubo['AppldRate'] >= 550.000  and featAdubo['AppldRate']< 600.000:
            featAdubo['classe'] = 4
            area_cls4 += featAdubo['area_ha']
        else:
            featAdubo['classe'] = 5
            area_cls5 += featAdubo['area_ha']
    else:
        progress.setText("Aplicacao zerada em AppIdRate: %" % featAdubo.id()) 

    vrAdubo.updateFeature(featAdubo)

vrAdubo.commitChanges()
```

Comment: What do you mean with: 'the process has stopped'. Which error message do you get? Without knowing this, I would suggest to call `changeAttributeValue()` instead of `updateFeature()`. Even better in this case: `provVrAdub.changeAttributeValues({featAdubo.id(): {fieldindex, class_value}})` with fieldindex as `provVrAdub.fieldNameMap()['classe']`

Comment: @Detlev  I sorry, my english is bad, the process "not responding" in taskmanager and was running a few hours, the file is a shapefile with 180.000 polygons. So 180.000 registries. Any error messages. Just stops.

Comment: Ok. Please try to change your code to change attributes on the dataProvider. The documentation states the `updateFeature()` '... needs to query the datasource on every call' -  this sounds like poor performance. And writing to dataProvider lacks the overhead of editing the layer.

Comment: For testing I try this:`fin_id = 1

for featAdubo in iterVrAdub:
    provVrAdub.changeAttributeValue(featAdubo.id(), featAdubo['id'].index, fin_id, QVariant())
    fin_id = fin_id + 1
    
vrAdubo.commitChanges()`But return QgSVectorProvider don't have changeAttributeValue

Comment: changeAttributeValues(). Did you miss the trailing "s"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `QgsMapLayer.updateFeature()` on many features is time consuming. The documentation states that `updateFeature()` *'... needs to query the datasource on every call'*. In your case that is 180.000 times a maximum of 180.000 features.

Another aspect is to edit a layer. Editing layer brings some overhead for transaction management. I think in your use case this is not necessary.

You gain performance with methods writing once to the data provider, namely `changeAttributeValues()`. Replace the if..else construct and updateFeatures() in your code with following lines (elif must be filled in):

```
fieldindex = provVrAdub.fieldNameMap()['classe']
update_dict = {}

for featAdubo in iterVrAdub:
    # ...
    if featAdubo['AppldRate'] < 400.000:
        class_value = 1
    # elif ...
    # else:
    #     ...
    update_dict[featAdubo.id()] = {fieldindex: class_value}

provVrAdub.changeAttributeValues(update_dict)
```